# Azure mobile services (android), query for average

Tags: android, azure

I'm developing an app for android with Windows Azure mobile services, it is working good but I havent figured out how to make a query that returns a simple average of a table filtered with a where clause.

I have tried the MobileServiceTable object, but its not woking. Thanks.

Comment: You can create a custom API to do this. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-call-custom-api/

Comment: That worked nice and I learned a new thing. Thank you.